# How to show a list of marks as barplot in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Let's suppose I have a dictionary of students name and their marks like `{'Andy':78,'Bob':65,'John':87,'Alex':72}`
How can show this as barplot in seaborn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list()` in the dictionary and its values:

```
data = {'Andy':78,'Bob':65,'John':87,'Alex':72}
sns.barplot(list(data.values()),list(data))
```

Output:

[image]